# Return multiple json objects from controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I return multiple json objects but i don't know how to return that objects. I want to get returned json objects and send them to ajax request. This is my ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult AutoCompleteEventName(string eventName)
        {
            Event ev = new Event();
            ev.Name = eventName;
            var searchEvent = EventService.Instance.Search(ev);
            var totalCount = EventService.Instance.SearchCount(ev);           
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send object's list, you can do it with this way:

```
var yourObjectList = EventService.Instance.LoadSomeEvents();

List<object> objectList = new List<object>();

foreach (var event in yourObjectList)
{
     objectList.Add(new
                   {
                        id = event.Id,
                        name = event.Name,
                    });
}

return Json(objectList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return Json(new { searchEvent = searchEvent , totalCount  = totalCount }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Answer (score 1):

in controller 
return result as below

```
 var returnField = new { searchEvent  = "searchEvent", totalCount = totalCount.ToString() };
return Json(returnField, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

in Ajax Request

```
 success: function (data) {
var searchEvent  = data.searchEvent;
var totalCount =data.totalCount 
}
```